# Is part of the sequence of independent identically distributed random variables still iid?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, iid

if $x_0,x_1,...x_n$ be iid (independenta and identically distributed) random variables. The question is that the $x_0,x_3,...x_{n-1}$ is also iid?

Comment: This is your second question about *iid* variables that is immediately answered by considering the definition of *iid.*  It might serve you better to study that definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; still each random variable is independent of the others, and still each random variable has the same distribution